# Indice fuera de los limites de la matriz - C#

Tags: c#, array

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, estoy tratando de hacer comparacion de numeros dentro de un Array, solo que me da un error de Indice fuera de los limites de la matriz. Espero me puedan ayudar, se los agradeceria muchismimo, les dejo mi codigo

```
if ((array[0]) > (array[1]))
{
    poss = true;
}
else
{
    poss = false;
}
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if ((array[i]) < (array[i + 1])  && poss == true)
    {
        h++;
        poss = false;
    }
    if ((array[i]) > (array[i + 1]) && poss == false)
    {
        h++;
        poss = true;
    }
}

eh = ((n * 2) - 1) / 3;
vh = ((n * 16) - 29) / 90;
zcal = (h - eh) / Math.Sqrt(vh);
MessageBox.Show(zcal.ToString());
```

Mi error ocurre cuando llega a la siguiente linea de código:

```
if ((array[i]) < (array[i + 1])  && poss == true)
```

Mi `Array` es de 20 números

Comment: Prueba reemplazar `for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)` por  `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length-1; i++)`

Comment: @FranIslas me funciono perfectamente tu respuesta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas así como se ha comentado la solución es la siguiente:

reemplazar

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
```

por

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length-1; i++)
```

Pero me ha parecido correcto explicar el porqué, principalmente para los futuros visitantes.

Bien el error ocurría en tu caso al tener un array de 20 números por ejemplo.

Al llamar la propiedad length de el array esta devuelve la cantidad de datos que contiene, en este caso como ejemplo son 20.

Si recordamos los array contienen múltiples datos que se guardan en diferente dirección dentro de ellos es decir en una posición específica y nos referimos a esa posición por medio de un index que se expresa en números y ahí esta el punto en como se expresan las posiciones del array.

Ya que la propiedad **Length**  nos devuelve la cantidad de datos podríamos pensar que podemos hacer un ciclo con ese valor para recorrer el array. Por ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
```

Pero como vimos en en esta pregunta eso no funcionará. Ya qué:

En el ejemplo tenemos un array de 20 datos.

Pero no hay una posición de datos 20, pero porqué?

Porque las posiciones de datos en los array como todo en programación empiezan por **0**. Exacto el primer dato de nuestro array se guardara en la posición **0**. Entonces si tenemos 20 datos y las posiciones de datos empiezan desde **0** tenemos desde las posición **0** hasta la **19** con datos(si contamos desde 0 hasta 19 tenemos un total de 20 números).

Sabiendo esto nuestro ciclo for deberíamos empezar el ciclo en 0 para poder utilizar la variable del ciclo para acceder a los datos:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)

var obtenerDatos = array[i];
```

Y de esa manera obtenemos todos los datos de un array.

También se puede evitar confusiones podemos usar un ciclo especial que es el
[foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in).

Comment: Muchas gracias por tan buena explicacion, ahora me quedo mucho mas claro mi problema.

Comment: De nada, cualquier duda ya sabes que hacer..